# Как изменить директорию сайта?

Tags: php, html

Подскажите как превратить из вот примерной ссылки "http://мойсайт.ру/форум" вот такую ссылку "http://форум.мойсайт.ру"

Answer (score 1):

Это немного разные вещи первое  "http://мойсайт.ру/форум" говорит что у вас сайт мойсайт.ру и на нем есть папку /форум. Ну или что то берется из базы по такому адресу если настроены обработка URL по каким то правилам. Но без всяких наворотов с переадресацией форум это папка.
Второй адрес [http://форум.мойсайт.ру](http://xn--l1adgmc.xn--80arbjktj.xn--p1ag)   Это доменное имя, третьего уровня. Тесть есть сайт с именем [http://мойсайт.ру](http://xn--80arbjktj.xn--p1ag) и есть сайт с именем [http://форум.мойсайт.ру](http://xn--l1adgmc.xn--80arbjktj.xn--p1ag) зарегистрированные на DNS серверах. Так что имея например домен [http://мойсайт.ру](http://xn--80arbjktj.xn--p1ag) можно создать  [http://мойсайт.форум.ру](http://xn--80arbjktj.xn--l1adgmc.xn--p1ag) зарегистрировать его на dns серверах и это будет отдельный сайт. Хотя находиться и первый и второй могут физически на одном сервере. или Хостинге.